# Reference a .NET Standard 1.6 library from a .net library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I'm trying to use a library in my application, I'm kinda new to this I'm following this instructions,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/consuming-library-with-visual-studio?tabs=csharp

where basically I've opened the library solution and added a new project to it,
however when I run I get the following error:

Project '..\src\gdax.netcore.csproj' targets 'netstandard1.6'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'.  GdApp1

I'm not sure how to fix this, I've tried changing various target versions in both the library and my project, if I set my project target to 4.6.1 I get missing directives or assembly references, related to the library I'm using.

I'm trying to use this library https://github.com/sefbkn/gdax.netcore 
my code is basically a straight copy of their example at this point

the missing references and errors are:

```
The type or namespace name 'RequestAuthenticator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  

The type or namespace name 'ProductClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

The type or namespace name 'gdax' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  

The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
```

Comment: See the compatibility table here: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md

Comment: right I did have a look at that, so the .netstandard 1.6 should be compatible with 4.6.1 framework right? how comes I get missing references when I change to that?

Comment: Can you explain the missing references in more detail? What library are you trying to use and what code are you using to call it? Posting code will help us help you out.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help Lesscode, I've updated the main post

Comment: How are you referencing this library? I don't see a Nuget package for it, so are you just adding the project code to your solution? Make sure you have the correct `using Boukenken.Gdax;` declaration in your source code.

Comment: oh I see I was using the wrong name in the using directive, where should I look for the correct one that you mentioned?

Comment: It all depends on which classes you're using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Comment: The simplest, would be to use .NET Framework 4.7.1 and above, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/17/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-1/

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple steps here

1. Check you are using a recent version of VS (suggested 15.5.* for .NET 4.7.1+netstandard support)
2. Target at least .NET 4.6.1 to reference netstandard1.6 libraries
3. Follow https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31 to resolve library loading issues. This involves enabling automated binding redirect generation for the application using it and modifying the csproj for unit tests.

Alternatively, wait for .NET 4.7.2 and Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6 to remove the need for manual steps.

Answer (score -1):

You also need to NETStandard.Library nuget package to your project that tries to use any .Net Standard dll.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/